# How do I call a method that has a variable passed through it?

Tags: java

I'm trying to call a method from within another method. I'm understanding this simply enough, until one of those methods needs a variable carried through, and then nothing I try works.

I know that I could do this in one method, but my coursework needs me to lay it out in such a way. Why doesn't this work?

```
public class test2 {
   public static void testMethod() {
      int randomNumber = 1;
   }
   public static void anotherTestMethod(int randomNumber) {
      System.out.println(randomNumber);
   }
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      anotherTestMethod();
   }
}
```

Comment: What is your assignment? It's not clear to me what you've been asked to do. I have a good guess, but let's hear it from the horse's mouth.

Comment: Well, you can start by passing the number to the method. Eg. `anotherTestMethod(6)` ...

Answer (score 0):

You are calling a method that has an int parameter in its signature. You should pass that parameter when calling the method. I think you are trying to use a global variable, in that case, you should declare it outside any method, as a part of the class.

Answer (score -1):

```
public class test2 {
   public static int testMethod() {
      int randomNumber = 1;
      return randomNumber;
   }
   public static void anotherTestMethod() {
      System.out.println(testMethod());
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      anotherTestMethod();
   }
}
```